# Communication between Backbone.js collection and Ruby on Rails service with parameters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, parameter-passing

I'm currently involved in making my first serious web application. I've spent the last few months frantically researching the web, including stackoverflow, studying many different technologies. HTML, CSS, Javascript, backbone.js, ruby, rails, etc. I'm still very new to all these technologies, but have somehow managed to create a first version of my javascript-driven user interface.

Basically, what I'm making is a scheduling application for a music school, allowing the user to see the schedule of a teacher per week, and also apply for lessons in an open slot. I've built the javascript interface first, using Backbone.js, which consists of a table that displays already scheduled lessons, open slots, and things like closing days etc.

This table "view" has as input a Backbone Collection called Schedule, with model = Lesson, and has metadata startDate and endDate. In the render function of this collection the whole table is built based on the lessons inside.

I want this application to be "one-page", like a desktop application, so no page loading. For that I want to build this Schedule Collection by requesting all the information in a JSON format. The "query" towards the server should contain a Teacher id and a start and end date. The server should then pass me all the lessons in a JSON format, and I will then make a collection out of it, and then render it to make the whole table.

So I think I know how I want everything to look like, but have no clue how to actually make it in practice:

1. On the server side I'll be using Ruby On Rails. In the past few days I've learned how to make the basic RESTful webservices with the scaffold method, but how would I go about making an operation in Ruby On Rails that receives thesse parameters like TeacherID and start and endTime? How can I pass these along to the server and have Rails query the database and render the resulting lessons into JSON?
2. How is the best way to build this on the client-side? Should I be using the Backbone.sync method on the Schedule Collection to load up all this data? I suppose I should overwrite the Schedule.sync method with a call towards this RoR service? Does Backbone provide any methods to call the aforementioned service with the necessary parameters? And can I somehow parse this into the Schedule Collection?

Please do excuse me for the very broad questions, but I'm lost in all the technologies that are hiding a lot of logic (I come from a Java background were I was building everything with more low level steps) but any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call Collection.fetch(), not Collection.sync() here.

Note that fetch() accepts a hash of options, and those options' "data" key is query parameters for the request.

So, you can pass conditions like so:

```
var Lesson = Backbone.Model.extend();

var SheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/rest/lesson',
    model: Lesson
});

var sheduleCollection = new SheduleCollection();
sheduleCollection.fetch({
    data: {where: {start: 'X', end: 'Y', teacher: 'Z'}}
});
```

Of course, you need then teach your back-end (RoR in this case) to parse these parameters and build correct database query using them.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get data like TeacherID, start and endTime you may use simply jQuery.ajax method. I don't into Rails, but I suppose that this is simple in Rails too. You'll have to catch your data request on server (like you catch usual page request) and return TeacherID or whatever you want, then you'll get returned data in you success method, [check documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). As I've understood you correctly you need that meta-data in your table-view, so you may put that logic in your table-view initialize method.
2. To load Schedule Collection's data via RESTful api you can call ScheduleCollection.fetch(), do not forget to set params like model and url (like '/rest/schedule', for example) to your ScheduleCollection.